# Create Master SP in Teradata to call other SP dynamically

Tags: sql, teradata

```
REPLACE  PROCEDURE PD_CCP_FN_DB.master_proc_TEST()
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(4000);
    FOR rec AS Cur CURSOR FOR 
       select SP_NAME from  WRK_QA_CCP_ATOMIC_DB.SP_CALL
     DO
       SET STMT= ' CALL ' || rec.SP_NAME || '(''PII_SUPP_SMRY_TXN'') ';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT;
     END FOR;
END;
```

Comment: REPLACE  PROCEDURE PD_CCP_FN_DB.master_proc_TEST()
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(4000);
 FOR rec AS Cur CURSOR FOR 
select SP_NAME from  WRK_QA_CCP_ATOMIC_DB.SP_CALL
 DO
 SET STMT= ' CALL ' || rec.SP_NAME || '(''PII_SUPP_SMRY_TXN'') ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT;
   END FOR;
END;

Comment: There is no question here at all...